# Library Not found error for iOS Device in Xcode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am trying to run my app on device but it is giving error for device working fine for iPhone simulator.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Documents/TEST/../CorePlotDemo/CorePlotDemo'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/TEST/../CorePlotDemo/CorePlotDemo'
ld: library not found for -lsqlite3.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How To solve this error, I also tried with Library Search Path but not working .

Comment: Do the directories `/Users/Documents/TEST/../CorePlotDemo/CorePlotDemo` and `/Users/TEST/../CorePlotDemo/CorePlotDemo` exist on your system? I suspect they do not. In particular, the second path would require a user named `CorePlotDemo`.

Comment: actually I deleted username before posting question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add library libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a

And set path in build Setting -> Search Path -> Library Search Path -> $(inherited) "$(SRCROOT)/Libs/CorePlot"

This is the path of libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a.

Comment: not working ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Documents/TEST Poker/Poker 08:09:2012 2/Libs/CorePlot'
ld: library not found for -lsqlite3.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I got the issue .It was not because of core plot actually libsqlite library was deleted from my system and that code was working fine on other machine. Thanks for help :) Although your answer is correct